# Django rest framework basic auth for api store in api_credentials table

Tags: python, django, basic-authentication

I want to use Basic Auth for a api which receive JSON data and store in the database table. The problem I faced is to setup Basic Auth for the API. The API username and password store in api_credentials table in 2 separate column. Its has no relation with user table.

In my api.py

```
class EventDataViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                         mixins.ListModelMixin,
                         viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = models.EventData.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.EventDataSerializer
    authentication_classes = (eventdataapiauth,) # I write this class
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
```

eventdataapiauth is my auth class. How can I write my authentication code in that class. Or is there any other better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as per [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#how-authentication-is-determined), you can't use the `authentication_classes`, because you don't have any relation to user model with credentials. And you can't use permission classes either, because `permissions.isAuthenticated` checks if request has any user instance and if its authenticated, like `if request.user.is_authenticated`.

So you can take this approach instead with a decorator. Try like this:

```
import binascii
import base64
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.authentication import get_authorization_header
from rest_framework import HTTP_HEADER_ENCODING



def check_authenticated(function):
    def wrapper(obj, request, *args, **kw):
        auth = get_authorization_header(request).split()
        if not auth or auth[0].lower() != b'basic':
            msg = _("Not basic authentication.")
            return Response(data={'error': msg}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

        if len(auth) == 1:
            msg = _('Invalid basic header. No credentials provided.')
            return Response(data={'error': msg}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        elif len(auth) > 2:
            msg = _('Invalid basic header. Credentials string should not contain spaces.')
            return Response(data={'error': msg}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

        try:
            auth_parts = base64.b64decode(auth[1]).decode(HTTP_HEADER_ENCODING).partition(':')
        except (TypeError, UnicodeDecodeError, binascii.Error):
            msg = _('Invalid basic header. Credentials not correctly base64 encoded.')
            return Response(data={'error': msg}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

        userid, password = auth_parts[0], auth_parts[2]
        # Your auth table specific codes
        if AuthTable.objects.filter(username=userid, password=password).exists():  # my dummy code
            return function(obj, request, *args, **kw)
        else:
            msg = _('User not found.')
            return Response(data={'error': msg}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
    return wrapper
```

Now use this in your ViewSet like this:

```
class EventDataViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                         mixins.ListModelMixin,
                         viewsets.GenericViewSet):
     queryset = models.EventData.objects.all()
     serializer_class = serializers.EventDataSerializer
     authentication_classes = []
     permission_classes = []

     @check_authenticated
     def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
          return super(EventDataViewSet, self).create(request,*args, **kwargs)

     @check_authenticated
     def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
          return super(EventDataViewSet, self).list(request,*args, **kwargs)
```

But if you have a relation between `auth_table` and `User` model, then you can override `BasicAuthetication` class like this:

```
class EventDataApiAuth(BasicAuthentication):

    def authenticate_credentials(self, userid, password, request=None):
        user = AuthData.objects.get(username=userid, password=password).user  # assuming auth_table has a ForeignKey relation to User
        return (user, None)
```

And use it in `authentication_classes`. Hope it helps!!